# How can I insert the word "Ad" above an dfp-ad, mark ad with "Ad" on site? Doubleclick for publishers small business

Tags: html, google-dfp, advertisement-server

Can I insert html in Google doubleclick-tag?

```
<!-- /123456789/outsider -->
<div id='div-gpt-ad-123456789999-7'>
<p>Ad</p> <!-- is this ok? -->
<script type='text/javascript'>
googletag.cmd.push(function() { googletag.display('div-gpt-ad-123456789999-7'); });
</script>
</div>
```

I want the word "Ad" to be placed above the ad. If no ad is present I dont want to show "Ad". Or can I make a label in DFP directly?

Answer (score 0):

DFP offers you an event where you can check if the slot is empty or not.

```
 googletag.pubads().addEventListener('slotRenderEnded', function(event) {

    if (!event.isEmpty && event.slot.getSlotElementId() === "div-gpt-ad-123456789999-7") {
         //Here insert the code to set the 'Ad' text    
    }
});
```